# snowflake output in table format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I queried a external table(pointed to CSV file) in snowflake , The results are displayed in JSON format.

How can I retrieve my results in tabular format without use any such below sql . I wanted to do `select * from table` and I expect it to display in display format.

```
select
value:c1::int as month_num
,value:c2::string as month_name
from mytable
;
```

any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view on your table and use select * on the view

```
create or replace view my_view as 
select value:c1::int as month_num ,value:c2::string as month_name from mytable;


select * from my_view;
```